# How to make an animated gif with a transparent background without overlap?

Tags: gimp, animation, transparency, gif

When I try to make a gif with two frames both of which have a transparent background in GIMP, what happens is that the first frame looks OK, then the second frame appears on top of it, such that you can see both frames at the same time.

How can I make animated gif in which all of the frames have a transparent background but each time a frame appears, the previous frame disappears completely ?

Answer (score 14):

When exporting/saving (depends on version) your work as GIF, you have several options for it. One way for that, what you probably want, could be done by choosing from "Frame disposal where unspecified" option "One frame per layer (replace)".

Comment: I also had to make sure that I checked off "Use disposal entered above for all frames" -- I think because by default every layer had the "(combine)" on it.

Answer (score 12):

For the current version (2.8.0), in the name for each frame layer, include `(replace)`. For example:

```
frame 1(250ms)(replace)
```

That will tell gimp to replace instead of stacking. Note that you can use the stacking for some pretty cool effects as well.

Answer (score 1):

Others answers involving gimp did not work for me. What fixed my gif is the command

`gifsicle -U --disposal=previous -O2 source.gif > target.gif`

Comment: Both other answers are valid though.

Comment: hence the "for me". I used gimp osx version, maybe it is related.

Comment: Certainly not... You must have missed something.

Comment: Nope, but my gimp version may be outdated. Anyway, just providing an alternative.

Comment: I also had to make sure that I checked off "Use disposal entered above for all frames"

Comment: I tried and It didn't work, but then I tried re-stitching my gif from the frames from scratch `gifsicle --loop --delay=2 --disposal=previous *.gif > c3.gif` which is essentially the same thing, and it worked! Thanks so much @kraymer for the help!